# Python скрипт распознается как вирус

Tags: python

Возникла проблема. Есть python проект, который с помощью pyinstaller был конвертирован из py в exe. После этого мой антивирус считает этот файл вирусом и удаляет. Что с этим делать? (Если что программа - не вирус)

Comment: коронавирус добрался и до файлов)

Comment: Сообщите разработчикам антивируса о ложном срабатывании, например

Comment: @andreymal, тоже когда-то сталкивался с такой проблемой. Но для каждого антивируса так делать же не будешь :)

Answer (score 1):

Так происходит потому что pyinstaller распаковывает файлы и интерпретатор питона в папке temp, поэтому антивирусам не нравятся такие программы. Также можно получить исходный код вашей программы если вы скомпилировали через pyinstaller.
Попробуйте использовать nuitka - https://pypi.org/project/Nuitka/

Comment: каким образом написанное вами отвечает на заданный вопрос? уточните это, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вашего ответа, нажав [edit].